# MSCRM 2011 EntitCollection and LINQ empty resultset

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have an **EntityCollection ec** in C# which has been populated with all Accounts.
Now I want another List or EntityCollection from **ec** which has all the accounts with status active.

I am using Linq for the same.

But both form of LINQ returns a an empty result while **ec** has 354 number of records

```
var activeCRMEC = (from cl in ec.Entities
                where cl.Attributes["statecode"].ToString()=="0"
                select cl);
```

OR

```
var activeCRMEC = ec.Entities.Where(x => x.Attributes["statecode"].ToString() == "0");
```

Each time the resultset is empty and I am unable to iterate over it. And 300 or so accounts are active, I have checked. 
Same thing happens when I use some other attribute such as name etc.

Please be kind enough to point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Generate Early Bound Classes to  write **Linq Queries.**

or Else

You can Write Linq Queries Using **Late Bound** Using **OrganizationServiceContext Class**.

For Your Reference:

```
 OrganizationServiceContext OrgServiceCOntext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

 var RetrieveAll = OrgServiceCOntext.CreateQuery("account").
                ToList().Where(w => (w.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value ==0)).Select(s=>s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a few hints, and then tell you what I'm guessing your issue is.

First, use early bound entities.  If you've never generated them before, use the [earlybound generator](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/), you'll save yourself a lot headaches.

Second, if you can't use early bound entities, use the [GetAttribute()](http://crmentropy.blogspot.com/2013/08/entitygetattributevalue-explained.html) method on the Entity class.  It'll convert types for you, and handle null reference issues.

Your LINQ expressions look to be correct, so either the ec.Entities doesn't have any entities in it that match the criteria of "statecode" equaling 0, or you possibly have some differed execution occurring on your IEnumerables. Try calling `ToList()` on the activeCRMEC immediately after the LINQ statement to ensure that is not your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The statecode is an OptionSetValue, you should cast it in this way

```
((OptionSetValue)cl.Attributes["statecode"]).Value == 0
```

or

```
cl.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 0
```

Both ways are valid and you should ask for the Value that it is an int.

Hope this can help you.